# Access DOM element inside $.getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, getjson

I'm developing an application that iterates over some `DOM` elements, and performs an `Ajax` request for each one of those elements. The problem is that I cannot access each `DOM` element inside the callback function.

```
$('.class').each(function() {
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        $(this).attr('id', data.id); // $(this) is not accessible
    });
});
```

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a variable, as the value of `this` changes for each function call, and inside the callback for $.getJSON `this` is no longer the element.

```
$('.class').each(function() { 

    var self = this;

    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        self.id = data.id;
    });
});
```

Another option would be the built in arguments in `each()`

```
$('.class').each(function(index, element) { 
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        element.id = data.id;
    });
});
```

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple, it works even in asynchronous mode. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You could do this to not have to execute an assignment.

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
  $(this).attr('id', data.id); // $(this) is accessible
}.call(this));
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/8EWvC/4/

Comment: Thank you very much but this answer does not work inside the `each` loop.

Comment: Yes it does. Take a look at the link.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be to use `Function#bind`, like this:

```
$('.class').each(function() {
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        $(this).attr('id', data.id);
    }.bind(this)); // Pass `this` into the getJSON and now `this` should be the DOM element
});
```

What this does is that whatever you pass into `bind` will be set to `this` inside the function. You can find out more by reading the [MDN here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: This answer also works perfectly! And a little simpler :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Either you can cache your selector in a variable like it:

```
$('.class').each(function() {
   var $this = $(this); // cache it here
   $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
      $this.attr('id', data.id); // $(this) is not accessible
   });
});
```

or if you are able to change your `$.getJson()` to traditional `$.ajax()` then you can use `context:this,` param:

```
$('.class').each(function() {
   $.ajax({
      url : url, 
      dataType: 'json',
      context: this,
      success: function(data) {
          this.id = data.id; // $(this) is not accessible
      }
   });
});
```